# GCD of an array

Tags: java, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

You are given an array A of integers of size N. You will be given Q queries where each query is represented by two integers L, R. You have to find the gcd(Greatest Common Divisor) of the array after excluding the part from range L to R inclusive

MY Approach :

```
public static int gcd(int a ,int b) {
    if(b == 0) return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}

for(int j = 0; j < Q; j++) {
    int l = in.nextInt();
    int r = in.nextInt();
    ans = 0;
    for(int k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
        if(k < l || k > r) ans = gcd(a[k], ans);
    }
    System.out.println(ans);
}
```

But This approach give me Time Limit Exceeded Error How can i improve my alogrithm

Comment: Where's gcd coming from?

Comment: Have you thought about breaking it up in two; `k=0...<l` and `j=r+1...<n` type of thing.

Comment: Are you sure that `for(int k=1;k<=n;k++)` is correct? Shouldn't it be `for(int k=0;k<n;k++)`?

Comment: @honk i have used 1 based indexing for an array , when i am taking as input  so that's why start from 1

Comment: @user162091: You should have included that information in your question right from the start. Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently we can only poke around. Are you sure that your program is working correctly? If not, then please read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: This is a question from the ongoing CodeChef [contest](http://www.codechef.com/JAN15/problems/GCDQ). Please delete this question.

Comment: @NavedAlam as I've said before, asking CodeChef questions doesn't violate any of the Stack Overflow terms and conditions. **You cannot insist that such questions be deleted.** If you have an issue with this, raise it on Meta Stack Overflow and request a change to the t&c to ban questions from ongoing competitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can precompute the gcd for each prefix and suffix(let's call it `gcdPrefix` and `gcdSuffix`) in `O(n * log MAX_A)` time(just iterate over your array from left to right and store the current gcd, then do the same thing from right to left). The answer for a `(L, R)` query is `gcd(gcdPrefix[L - 1], gcdSuffix[R + 1]`)(so it is `O(log MAX_A)` operations per query). The total time complexity is `O((n + q) * log MAX_A)`. I think it should be fast enough.

Comment: @user162091 What exactly is unclear? Each query is a union of a prefix and a suffix(because we exclude the middle part, according to the problem statement).

Comment: ` Each query is a union of a prefix and a suffix` what does it mean please explain it how `gcd(gcdPrefix[L - 1], gcdSuffix[R + 1])` this thing working

Comment: @user162091 We exclude the part `[L, R]`. What does remain? `[1, L - 1]` and `[R + 1, N]`(a prefix and a suffix). gcd(a[1], ..., a[L - 1]) is `gcdPrefix[L - 1]`. gcd(a[R + 1], ..., a[N]) is `gcdSuffix[R + 1]`. That's why gcd(a[1], ..., a[L - 1], a[R + 1], ..., a[N]) is gcd(gcdPrefix[L - 1], gcdSuffix[R + 1]).