# Finding the greatest common divisor (GCD) of an array excluding some elements in minimum time

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I was doing a competitive programming question whereby you are given an array of numbers, and then a certain number of queries. For each query, you are given 2 integers, 'a' and 'b'. So you're supposed to output the GCD of the remaining elements in the array (excluding a, b , and all the elements in between).

For example, if the array is : 16, 8, 24, 15, 20 and there are 2 queries (2, 3) and (1, 3), then output 1 is: 1 and output 2 is: 5. 
Note that the indexing is 1 based.

Here is my code, in which I've implemented the basic idea with a function for finding the GCD of an array passed to it.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    while (t-- > 0) {   //This is the number of test cases
        String[] s1 = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(s1[0]);          //Number of elements in array
        int q = Integer.parseInt(s1[1]);          //Number of queries

        String[] s2 = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int[] arr = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(s2[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {            //for each query
            String[] s3 = br.readLine().split(" ");
            int a = Integer.parseInt(s3[0]) - 1;
            int b = Integer.parseInt(s3[1]) - 1;

            int[] copy = new int[n - b + a - 1];     //this is so that the original array doesn't get messed up

            int index = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {       //filing the array without the elements of the query
                if (j < a || j > b) {
                    copy[index] = arr[j];
                    index++;
                }
            }

            int fin = gcd(copy);
            System.out.println(fin);

        }

    }

}

private static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while (b > 0) {
        int temp = b;
        b = a % b; // % is remainder
        a = temp;
    }
    return a;
}

private static int gcd(int[] input) {        //simple GCD calculator using the fact that GCD(a,b,c) === GCD((a,b),c)
    int result = input[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++)
        result = gcd(result, input[i]);
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting AC on some of the parts (6 out of 10), and a TLE on the rest. Can someone suggest a better method to solve this problem, as my approach seems too slow, and almost impossible to be optimized any further?

Comment: Sorry, I do not get it how your examples got those values. For me `gcd(16,15,20) = 1` and `gcd(8,15,20) = 1`.

Comment: @GáborBakos Really sorry, I messed up there. Corrected. Also , I didn't mention 1 critical point there. Please check the first paragraph once again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCD of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753369/gcd-of-an-array)

Comment: @ILoveCoding Your answer there wasn't providing a correct solution( even though it is marked so), so I'd to ask another question.

Comment: @pkm It did provide a correct solution. What makes you think that it was wrong?

Comment: @ILoveCoding http://pastebin.com/hgL3FyYZ This is the solution that you provided. It's getting a very bad TLE so...

Comment: @pkm It is not an implementation of my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can just precompute gcd for all prefixes and suffixes. Each query is a union of a prefix and a suffix, so it takes `O(log MAX_A)` time to answer one. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Solution {

    static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        while (b != 0) {
            int t = a;
            a = b;
            b = t % b;
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        int tests = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for (int test = 0; test < tests; test++) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            int n = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            int q = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            int[] a = new int[n];
            parts = br.readLine().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                a[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
            int[] gcdPrefix = new int[n];
            int[] gcdSuffix = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                gcdPrefix[i] = a[i];
                if (i > 0)
                    gcdPrefix[i] = gcd(gcdPrefix[i], gcdPrefix[i - 1]);
            }
            for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                gcdSuffix[i] = a[i];
                if (i < n - 1)
                    gcdSuffix[i] = gcd(gcdSuffix[i], gcdSuffix[i + 1]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
                parts = br.readLine().split(" ");
                int left = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                int right = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                left--;
                right--;
                int res = 0;
                if (left > 0)
                    res = gcd(res, gcdPrefix[left - 1]);
                if (right < n - 1)
                    res = gcd(res, gcdSuffix[right + 1]);
                out.println(res);
            }
        }
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro, I'd already submitted an almost similar code, got a TLE. 
For the sake of it, I submitted this code as it is, even **this** got the TLE error at exactly the same sub-tasks where I got one.

Comment: @pkm It is a completely different code. If you are talking about the link you showed me in the comments to your question, it has nothing to do with this solution.

Comment: I realize that. I submitted another one after that, and now this. The problem still exists.

Comment: @pkm Did you try to use `PrintWriter` to speed up output?

Comment: Oh. Finally. Thanks for the reminder and guess what? It worked. Thanks for your help dude. And I'm sorry if I sounded too rude earlier in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

"Almost impossible to optimize further"?  Pshaw:

1. Add a cache of computed GCDs *of adjacent input elements* so they don't need to be re-computed.  For example, have a table that holds the GCD of `input[i]` and `input[j]`.  Note that this will be no more than half the size of the original input.
2. Compute the GDC of successive pairs of inputs (so you can take advantage of #1)

This could be extended to larger groups, at the cost of more space.

Comment: I think usually `gcd` is so fast (at least for small numbers), that cache non-locality might hurt more than recomputing the values.

Comment: So long as it speeds up the slow cases enough without slowing down the fast cases too much, we have a winner.

Comment: @ScottHunter I forgot to mention but the maximum value of n (size of array), is given to be 10^6. Thus, I can safely assume that storing all the pairs is going to take a lot more space than what is provided to me. (JBTW the problem excludes all elements **between a & b** along with a & b. I'd also forgot to mention that)

Answer (score 0):

What is crucial here is that the GCD of a set of numbers `A` is equal to the GCD of the GCDs of any partition of `A`. For example,

```
GCD(16, 8, 24, 15, 20) = GCD(GCD(16, 8), GCD(24, 15, 20))
```

I would exploit this fact by building some tree like structure. Lets write `GCD[i, j]` for the GCD of the set of elements with indices between `i` and `j`. For a given input of size `n`, I would store:

```
GCD[1, n]
GCD[1, n/2], GCD[n/2+1, n]
...
GCD[1, 2], GCD[2, 3] ... GCD[n-1, n]
```

That is, at every level of the tree the number of GCDs doubles and the size of the sets over which they are computed halves. Note that you will store `n-1` numbers this way, so you need linear extra storage. Computing them bottom-up, you will need to do `n-1` GCD operations as preprocessing.

For querying, you need to combine the GCDs such that exactly the two query indices are left out. As an example, lets have an array `A` with `n = 8` and we query `(2, 4)`.

- We cannot use `GCD[1, 8]`, because we need to exclude 2 and 4, so we go one level deeper in the tree.
- We cannot use `GCD[1, 4]`, but we can use `GCD[5, 8]`, because neither of the indices to exclude is in there. For the first half we need to go deeper.
- We cannot use `GCD[1, 2]`, nor `GCD[3, 4]`, so we go one level deeper.
- We simply use the elements `A[1]` and `A[3]`.

We now need to compute the GCD of `GCD[5, 8]`, `A[1]`, and `A[3]`. For the query, we need to do only 2 GCD calculations, instead of 5 in the naive way.

In general, you will spend `O(log n)` time searching the structure and will need `O(log n)` GCD calculations per query.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, but it is an overkill for this problem. We are only interested in a union of a prefix and suffix, so we can precompute gcd for all prefixes and suffixes and preform 1 gcd computation per query.

Comment: @ILoveCoding there are two excluded indices, right? So there should also be some infix?

Comment: It's true that we need the union of a prefix and suffix GCD, but computing them in itself takes a lot of time, as we'll loop over the entire array each time.

Comment: No, the entire `[a, b]` range is excluded. So there is no infix.

Comment: @pkm You can precompute gcd for prefixes and suffixes once. It is just two array traversals.

Comment: OK, then I misread the question. I'll still leave this answer here because I believe it would work (with a minor tweak) and is quite fast. Besides, it works for much more generic queries too.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele you have not misread the question. There was an update since then.